# Ember tutorial error: models/rental.js: line 4, col 12, 'attr' is not defined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm going through the main tutorial on the ember website and I got to the end of this page:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/tutorial/ember-data/

In the command prompt ember is saying this

```
models/rental.js: line 4, col 12, 'attr' is not defined.
```

It is referencing this bit

```
export default Model.extend({
    title: attr(),
    owner: attr(),
    city: attr(),
    type: attr(),
    image: attr(),
    bedrooms: attr()
});
```

When I reach the bottom of the tutorial, the page is just completely blank when it loads.

When I delete the `title: attr(),` bits that are erroring, the error goes away and the page loads the hard coded HTML but the variable fields aren't populated with anything. The looping functionality *does* occur though.

Can someone please help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is your Ember Data v2.5?

Comment: Yes I'm using the latest version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have forgot to import `attr` as shown in the tutorial :

```
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
```

Comment: Yep, I missed that line of code in the `app/models/rental.js` file. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please define you model in this path

```
app/models/rental.js
```

then include following code in renatal.js file

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
  title: attr(),
  owner: attr(),
  city: attr(),
  type: attr(),
  image: attr(),
  bedrooms: attr()
});
```

basically you are not importing attr and Model libraries from ember-data.